# Leverage multiple CPU cores for video rendering (VSE)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, video, performance

I have a 1950X Threadripper with 16 cores and even if I set the thread count to 16 manually in the performance section, it still only uses 1 core. Have Cycles renderer selected and both user preferences and the rendering properties are set to use CPU. Am I missing something?

Comment: What video rendering, VSE or animation sequence render straightly to video file? If it is VSE, then you can't utilize more than one core without spliting file and messing with ffmpeg concatenate command.

Comment: If you're rendering video (as Serge suggested) I suggest the Blender Render Controler.

Comment: Have a look at GDquest's video on faster rendering using the VSE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJQptYvXAnw

Comment: Thanks for the comments was able to get bpsrender up and running!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments! Figured it out:

I used BPSRender which is the root tool of the youtube video posted above. However it didn't work out of the box; needed to add blender to the system path in Windows for it to work.

https://gitlab.com/razcore/BPSRender
https://pypi.org/project/bpsrender/